# Perl script to check if possible to ssh to remote server

Tags: ssh, scripting, perl

I have a perl script in which i want to first check if it possible to ssh into the server before i actually do ssh. So if it possible to ssh, then go ahead and ssh into that server, otherwise handle this exception appropriately.

So i have this script that goes through a textfile with a list of databases, and tries to ssh into each server to perform a bash command that checks if the server is performing MySQL SST or not:

````
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.010;
use DBI;
use Encode;
use IO::File;
use JSON;
use utf8;

BEGIN {
    binmode STDERR, ':utf8';
    binmode STDIN, ':utf8';
    binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
}

my $time = localtime();
my $file = '/opt/db-servers/db.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $hostname = <$info>)  {
    chomp( $hostname );
    my $xtrabk_check = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql | grep wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2`;
    my $role_check = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql | grep donor`;
    my $error_log = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql`;
        if ( $xtrabk_check ne "" ){
            if ( $role_check ne "" ){
                my $cmd ="curl -vs -o /dev/null -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={\"channel\": \"#db-wsrep-status-log\", \"username\": \"db-wsrep-status-log\", \"text\": \"$time: $hostname: --role Donor \n```$error_log```\", \"icon_emoji\": \":scorpion:\"}' 2>&1 /dev/null https://hooks.slack.com/services/GVadasdd/B6LSMF5GV/BIApnzoIldfdsrw343wf";
                system($cmd);
            }
            else {
                my $cmd ="curl -vs -o /dev/null -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={\"channel\": \"#db-wsrep-status-log\", \"username\": \"db-wsrep-status-log\", \"text\": \"$time: $hostname: State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld \n```$error_log```\", \"icon_emoji\": \":scorpion:\"}' 2>&1 https://hooks.slack.com/services/GVadasdd/B6LSMF5GV/BIApnzoIldfdsrw343wf";
                system($cmd);
            }
       }
}
close $info;
````

So probably before performing the three lines below, i want to be able to know if that server is down (hence cannot ssh into it) or not (then ssh into it with the commands below):

```
my $xtrabk_check = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql | grep wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2`;
    my $role_check = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql | grep donor`;
    my $error_log = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql`;
```

How can i go about achieving this? By the way, the slack URL have been altered so security worries there.

I have added suggested code below, but still not seem to be working:

````
    ...
    while( my $hostname = <$info>)  {
    chomp( $hostname );
    my $ssh_ping = `$ssh_cmd\'@\'$hostname true`;
    if ( `$ssh_ping true`){
    my $xtrabk_check = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql | grep wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2`;
    my $role_check = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql | grep donor`;
    my $error_log = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql`;
        if ( $xtrabk_check ne "" ){
            if ( $role_check ne "" ){
                my $cmd ="curl -vs -o /dev/null -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={\"channel\": \"#db-wsrep-status-log\", \"username\": \"db-wsrep-status-log\", \"text\": \"$time: $hostname: --role Donor \n```$error_log```\", \"icon_emoji\": \":scorpion:\"}' 2>&1 /dev/null https://hooks.slack.com/services/GVadasdd/B6LSMF5GV/BIApnzoIldfdsrw343wf";
                system($cmd);
            }
            else {
                my $cmd ="curl -vs -o /dev/null -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={\"channel\": \"#db-wsrep-status-log\", \"username\": \"db-wsrep-status-log\", \"text\": \"$time: $hostname: State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld \n```$error_log```\", \"icon_emoji\": \":scorpion:\"}' 2>&1 https://hooks.slack.com/services/GVadasdd/B6LSMF5GV/BIApnzoIldfdsrw343wf";
                system($cmd);
            } 
       }
    } #end $ssh_ping if
} #end while
````

Comment: The simplest way to see if you can SSH is to SSH. `ssh $hostname true`, for example, and check the exit status. BTW, consider saving the output of `ssh $hostname ps -ef` and parsing it instead of running it thrice.

Comment: As muru says do a single ssh and collect the output into a variable for further processing such as `if($v =~ m/mysql/){...}`. You might like to add `-o ConnectTimeout=20`, for example, to the ssh if you want to not hang too long for slightly dead servers. Also `-o BatchMode=yes` is useful in scripts to ensure the ssh never tries to go interactive when things get broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
`ssh $hostname true`;

if ($? == 0) {
    ...;
} else {
    die "ssh failed";
}
```

Comment: I have updated the script adding some suggested lines. Please check updated par of the code above.

Comment: POST edited accordingly

Comment: The `true` command actually returns `0` (in Bash 0 is true, >0 is false).